# Openshift (OKD) 3.11 - Resuming cluster installation

Tags: installation, cluster

I'm installing OKD 3.11 using the ansible playbooks. Running the playbook deploy_cluster.yml fails every time because the script /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-origin-dns.sh messes up my /etc/resolv.conf file (even though I'm using static IP). The installation fails at the task "Master Install". Lat time I retried the playbook openshift-master/config.yml, as suggested by the logs, after fixing my DNS configuration manually. That playbook in particular finished without any issues.

The thing is, I don't know how to continue with the rest of the installation. Looking at the deploy_cluster playbook doesn't give me an idea of where to go next.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The answer was right there in the docs:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/running_install.html#running-the-advanced-installation-rpm [Retrying the Installation]